# pandas read_sql_query returns negative and incorrect values for Oracle Database number field containing positive values

Tags: python, sql, oracle, pandas, dataframe

I'm running pandas `read_sql_query` and cx_Oracle 6.0b2 to retrieve data from an Oracle database I've inherited to a DataFrame.

A field in many Oracle tables has data type `NUMBER(15, 0)` with unsigned values. When I retrieve data from this field the DataFrame reports the data as `int64` but the DataFrame values have 9 or fewer digits and are all signed negative. All the values have changed - I assume an integer overflow is happening somewhere.

If I convert the database values using `to_char` in the SQL query and then use pandas `to_numeric` on the DataFrame the values are type `int64` and correct.

I'm using Python 3.6.1 x64 and pandas 0.20.1. `_USE_BOTTLENECK` is `False`.

How can I retrieve the correct values from the tables without using `to_char`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing pandas and just using cx_Oracle still resulted in an integer overflow so in the SQL query I'm using:
`CAST(field AS NUMBER(19))`

At this moment I can only guess that any field between `NUMBER(11)` and `NUMBER(18)` will require an explicit `CAST` to `NUMBER(19)` to avoid the overflow.